# Prevent IHttpClientFactory to create DI scope for handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

1. I am using scoped service called `IOperationContextProvider` to hold some information about my current execution context (called `OperationContext`).
2. Whenever I start a new execution path (not only HTTP request, but some async impulses such as queue message, change feed change..), I create a dedicated DI service scope.
3. Any class can inject the provider and has access to this context (such as correlation ID).

For outgoing requests, I would like to configure to add the correlation ID to outgoing HTTP header, like this:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<IMyClass, MyClass>((serviceProvider, httpClient) =>
{
    var contextProvider = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOperationContextProvider>();
    var corrId = contextProvider.Context.CorrelationId;
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-corr-id", corrId);
});
```

However, I am unable to do this, because IHttpClientFactory creates scope for each handler it is creating and my context is not reachable from inside the HTTP client configuration. Same goes for adding HTTP message handlers, they are created in the same scope as the handler too.

[Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#outgoing-request-middleware):

> The `IHttpClientFactory` creates a separate DI scope for each handler. Handlers are free to depend upon services of any scope.

**Is there any way to reach the same scope as in which the HttpClient itself is being built?**

I only have found a way to where for the `MyClass`, where I also inject `HttpClient`, I inject the `IOperationContextProvider` too and configure manually the `HttpClient` but that is a bit cumbersome because it needs to be done everywhere:

```cs
public MyClass(HttpClient httpClient, IOperationContextProvider contextProvider)
{
    var corrId = contextProvider.Context.CorrelationId;
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-corr-id", corrId);
    this._httpClient = httpClient;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely don’t want the HttpClientFactory to create a service scope, then you can disable this behavior through the [`HttpClientFactoryOptions.SuppressHandlerScope` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.http.httpclientfactoryoptions.suppresshandlerscope). There isn’t a nice API to configure this though, so you will have to do something like this:

```
var httpClientBuilder = services.AddHttpClient<IMyClass, MyClass>(…);
services.Configure<HttpClientFactoryOptions>(httpClientBuilder.Name, options =>
{
    options.SuppressHandlerScope = true;
});
```

Alternatively, you could also create the delegating handler directly, without going through DI:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyClass, MyClass>(…)
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp =>
    {
        var contextProvider = sp.GetService<IOperationContextProvider>()
        return new MyHandlerWithoutDI(contextProvider);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I can set this behaviour. Amazing! I will try it and get back with result.

FWIW: I have already tried the second way (`AddHttpMessageHandler`) and it also unfortunately works in the handler's scope.

Comment: I have tried setting the suppression and it didn't help. I am still getting a different instance of the IOperationContextProvider.

In the docs for SuppressHandlerScope I also found following: _When operations that are part of `HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions` are executed they will be provided with the scoped `IServiceProvider` via `Services`. This includes retrieving a message handler from dependency injection, such as one registered using `AddHttpMessageHandler<THandler>(IHttpClientBuilder)`._
So I would expect this to work with custom Handler even without the suppression?

Comment: I also tried calling AddHttpMessageHandler (second option) and that one only gets called once with the first request and then never again, so it definitely works in some different scope.

Comment: Okay. Are you sure it’s not the implementation of `IOperationContextProvider` that’s not working as expected here?

Comment: FWIW: I have a Middleware setting up the scoped provider and when HTTP request comes, the middleware injects the provider and creates a context inside. I made sure that this happens before the HTTP client is being constructed, but just doesn't get the same instance of the provider.

Comment: I can inject `IOperationContextProvider` into let's say the same place where I inject `HttpClient` (into `MyClass`) and it receives the right instance of `IOperationContextProvider` with context inside.

Comment: I have tried `services.Configure(...)` and also `httpClientBuilder.Services.Configure(...)` with no luck

Comment: The `IOperationContextProvider` is just an instance that has its `Context` property filled with the `OperationContext` object which is created by the middleware. And then it is just living in the scope, there's nothing else to it.

Comment: @PremekVysoky did you find a solution for this? I've been bashing my head up against this one for days!

Comment: Both solutions do not work. Message handlers will still have their own scope.

Comment: This link seems to have described the issue fully. 
https://andrewlock.net/understanding-scopes-with-ihttpclientfactory-message-handlers/#an-example-of-unexpected-for-me-scoped-service-behaviour-in-ihttpclientfactory

Although I am not using Blazor so it did not solve my issues.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things thats also suggested is that the shared settings like the defaultrequestheaders be properly setup to avoid race conditions, if you are planning to use this client as a shared resource. This is in reference to your initial proposed workaround.

```
public MyClass(HttpClient httpClient, IOperationContextProvider 
      contextProvider)
      {
           var corrId = contextProvider.Context.CorrelationId;
           httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-corr-id", corrId);
           this._httpClient = httpClient;
       }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/